# Appium + Jenkins + Real device IOS

Tags: jenkins, appium, appium-ios

I need your help)

I need run appium test on ios real device in jenkins. I have jenkins on local machine.

My settings test:

c

```
apabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "IOS");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "11.2.1");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Iphone");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, 74859bb7c435945dafd8691be871ef96905030322);
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/Users/TEST/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-cvqckynzuuktkogfpkkkgyompmoj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/IntegrationApp.app");
```

Test successfully run if i run it in Intellij Idea + maven (mvn test) BUT when i run test in jenkins i have error:

```
/START APPIUM SERVER/....
[Appium] Creating new XCUITestDriver (v2.68.0) session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium] app: /Users/TEST/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-cvqckynzuuktkogfpkkkgyompmoj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/IntegrationApp.app
[Appium] platformVersion: 11.2.1
[Appium] platformName: IOS
[Appium] udid: 74859bb7c435945dafd8691be871ef96905030322
[Appium] deviceName: Iphone
[BaseDriver] Expected W3C "capabilities" to be a JSON Object but was provided with: []
[BaseDriver] Falling back to MJSONWP desired capabilities
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: b1797f6a-47ec-4dfc-8099-abc01aeaf878
[XCUITest] The 'idevice_id' program is not installed. If you are running a real device test it is necessary. Install with 'brew install libimobiledevice --HEAD'
[XCUITest] Error: Unknown device or simulator UDID: '74859bb7c435945dafd8691be871ef96905030322'
```

BUT libimobiledevice is already installed

Help me, please!

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem is related to your environment.
One thing you have to be aware is that your Jenkins test run by a Jenkins agent will use "Jenkins" user. Maybe, that's the origin of your problem.

Did you try to login as Jenkins on the machine that hosts the jenkins agent and run idevice_id from a command line to see if it is well found?

If it is not found, try to find the environment difference with Intellij.
Maybe you use Intellij with a different user ?
One thing you can do from intellij is to use the console and type:
`which idevice_id`
 to see where Intellij is finding it...

So, no direct answer but maybe this will help you...

Regards,

Loïc